# What is the term for sleepers (the crusty discharge that forms in the eyes during sleep)?

Tags: word-choice

I cannot find the term to accurately the term for "sleepers". Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper word for it is

目脂｛めやに｝

but more common words are:
目糞｛めくそ｝ and 目垢｛めあか｝

Comment: 目脂 is (much) more common; 目糞 is more slangy/vulgar.

Comment: In my experience, 目糞 is the most common in everyday, informal, speech. I don't know how it is statistically speaking though and I wouldn't use it formally.

Comment: My friends and I mostly use 目脂 in any situation, so it probably depends on the community (influenced by factors like regions, age, etc.). Sorry about sounding assertive.

Comment: No problem, you're not sounding assertive. We all have different experiences, and considering you're a native speaker I trust you more in this case than my limited experience (it's not everyday people talk about 目脂 ;) )